# Magnolia CMS - Custom SelectFieldDefinition - all available components on page

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm trying to extend the default SelectFieldDefinition of MagnoliaCMS to add dynamic options to this field.
The options I want to insert are the UUIDs of all content nodes of the current page.

But my Problem is that I'm not able to get the current context (page).

```
public class ComponentSelectFieldDefinition extends SelectFieldDefinition {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ComponentSelectFieldDefinition.class);

public ComponentSelectFieldDefinition() throws RepositoryException {
    super();

    try {
        Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(RepositoryConstants.WEBSITE);
        Iterable<Node> nodes = NodeUtil.collectAllChildren(session.getRootNode());

    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Actually I'm able to get the root node and I could iterate through all subNodes and add them to the SelectField, but I want to list only the subNodes of the current page the user is editing.

**SUMMARY:** Is it possible to get the current node path within the constructor of my class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible via a `Definition` however, you may get it if you were extend a `Field` class as such;

```
public SwitchableField(com.vaadin.data.Item relatedItem){
// you can do your manipulations of the given relatedItem here
}
```

I hope that helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As said above, not possible via definition, and if you want select you don't want to extend `SwitchableField` either. You need to extend `SelectFieldFactory` or if you just want to script it, look [here](https://github.com/rah003/scripted-select) resp [here](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blogs/jan-haderka/detail~@scriptable-and-queryable-select-fields~.html) on how to set options for select dynamically.

HTH,
Jan